# How to get the image width of the button image in a custom renderer?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, custom-renderer

I need to get the actual size of the image in my button renderer class. I need to get it in the `OnElementChanged` method from the variable `e.NewElement`.

I have tried to get it from `e.NewElement.ImageSource`, but it does not have a property width or size. If I debug it, the size is shown.

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
           //How to get width here from e ? 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look for the native counter-part, in Android like below:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
{
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            var image = Control?.GetCompoundDrawables()[0];
            if (image != null)
                //image.IntrinsicWidth
}
```

In iOS something like:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
{
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            var image = Control?.CurrentImage;
            if (image != null)
                //image.Size.Width
}
```